# WSDL-Content,binding: input type shown "literal" instead of the name of complextype

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, complextype

I deployed my webservice to tomcat. In the wsdl file the binding part is this:

```
<binding name="mywsPortBinding" type="tns:mywsInterface">
   <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
   <operation name="update">
        <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <input> <soap:body use="literal"/> </input>
        <output> <soap:body use="literal"/> </output>
   </operation>
</binding>
```

My Question: Why are the input and output types shown to be "literal"? 
As response this webservice sends back certain xml-complextyped data according to a specified xsd.  Why the copmlex type name is not shown in the wsdl instead?

Answer (score 2):

> In the case of 'literal', the abstract type definitions become the concrete definitions themselves (they're 'literal' definitions). In this case, you can simply inspect the XML Schema type definitions to determine the concrete message format. For example, the operation for the document/literal binding looks like this on the wire:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <m:Add xmlns:m="http://example.org/math/types/">
         <x>3.14159265358979</x>
         <y>3.14159265358979</y>
      </m:Add>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

> Notice that the SOAP Body simply contains an instance of the Add
>   element defined in the schema—this is what makes document/literal so
>   attractive.

Reference: [Understanding WSDL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996486.aspx#understand_topic6)

Answer (score 1):

In binding, "literal" is only defined the encoding style used, the complex Type name is showed in the "wsdl:message" definition, which is used in "wsdl:operation" in "wsdl:portType".

You should have something like this.
`

```
<xs:element name="update" type="tns:update"/>
<xs:complexType name="update">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="arg0" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="arg1" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="updateResponse" type="tns:updateResponse"/>
<xs:complexType name="updateResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="arg0" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<wsdl:message name="update">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:update" name="parameters"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="updateResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:updateResponse" name="parameters"/>
</wsdl:message> 



<wsdl:portType name="mywsInterface">
    <wsdl:operation name="update">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:update" name="update"/>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:updateResponse" name="updateResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>


<wsdl:binding name="mywsPortBinding" type="tns:mywsInterface">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="update">
        <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input name="update">
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="updateResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
```

` 
You can find more details and examples [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_wsdl)